# Wrong result with InitialDirContext.search()

Tags: java, ldap, enumeration

I have now tried to make this work for two days with two different libraries, but it just don't want to do what I want. So here's the problem:

I'm trying to load ldap entries with java, I'm using the "org.ietf.ldap"-Library.
Without problems, I can get single entries out of ldap, works perfectly, but with a special query, I only get one entry back from ldap, but there should be 15 entries.

Here's my code:

```
public void getEntries (String searchDN, int scope, InitialDirContext conn, String attributeName, String attributeValue) {
        List ansp = new ArrayList();
        final String QUERY = "cpMemDN=cn=usuid,ou=EMP,ou=COMPANY,o=META";
                    searchDN = "ou=SUPPORT, ou=ROLES, ou=SERVICES, ou=COMPANY, o=META";
        SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
        ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration enumeration = null;
```

```
    try {
        enumeration = context.search(searchDN, QUERY, ctrl);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Set<String> cns = new HashSet<String>();
    try {
              while (enumeration.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumeration.next();

        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So how I said, the enumeration only contains one entry instead of 15 entries (checked with LDAPBrowser). I also tried getting multiple entries with another query (cn=*) and it worked, I got multiple entries but the query can't be the problem because it works with LDAPBrowser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey it works now with the same code, just tried for 50 times haha. Strange thing, but solved.